# FIDEDUPERANGE ioctl doesn't behave as expected on btrfs

Tags: linux-mint, btrfs, deduplication, ioctl

According to [ioctl_fideduperange](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_fideduperange.2.html),

> The maximum size of *`src_length`* is filesystem dependent
> and is typically 16 MiB.

However, I've been able use `src_length` of > 1 Gib successfully with a single call to `ioctl`.  Is that warning about 16 MiB just a complete exaggeration, at least for `btrfs`?

Also, according to [the VFS documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/vfs.html),

> Implementations must handle callers passing in len == 0; this means “remap to the end of the source file”.

However, when I try setting `src_length` to `0`, the `ioctl` call succeeds but without doing anything.

Am I misreading these two sentences, or does the `btrfs` implementation simply not conform (well) to the documentation?  I'm testing on Linux Mint 20 with kernel `5.4.0-62-generic`.  I'm using `filefrag -sv FILE1 FILE2` to check the block-level allocation of the files, to see if they're duplicated or not.  I'm using the program below to deduplicate the files.  The files in question are on a RAID-1 `btrfs` filesystem (on LUKS-encrypted partitions) created with `sudo mkfs.btrfs -mraid1 -draid1 /dev/mapper/sda1_crypt /dev/mapper/sdb1_crypt`.

Scenario:

```
$ cp -f file1 file2
$ filefrag -sv file1 file2   # see that files use different extents (are not deduplicated)
$ myprog file1 file2
$ filefrag -sv file1 file2   # see that files use the same extents (have been deduplicated)
```

Program to deduplicate two files:

```
// deduplicate srcfile and targetfile if contents are identical
// usage:  myprog srcfile targetfile
// compile with:  gcc myprog.c -o myprog

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   struct stat st;
   long size;
   __u64 buf[2048];        /* __u64 for proper field alignment */
   struct file_dedupe_range *range = (struct file_dedupe_range *)buf;

   memset(range, 0, sizeof(struct file_dedupe_range));
   memset(&range->info, 0, sizeof(struct file_dedupe_range_info));

   long srcfd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
   if (srcfd < 0) { perror("open-src"); exit(1); }
   if (fstat(srcfd, &st) < 0) { perror("stat-src"); exit(1); }
   size = st.st_size;

   long tgtfd = open(argv[2], O_RDWR);
   if (tgtfd < 0) { perror("open-tgt"); exit(1); }
   if (fstat(tgtfd, &st) < 0) { perror("stat-tgt"); exit(1); }
   if (size != st.st_size) {
      fprintf(stderr, "SIZE DIFF\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   range->src_offset = 0;
   range->src_length = size;
// range->src_length = 0;                    // I expected this to work
   range->dest_count = 1;
   range->info[0].dest_fd = tgtfd;
   range->info[0].dest_offset = 0;

   while (range->src_length > 0) {
      if (ioctl(srcfd, FIDEDUPERANGE, range) < 0) { perror("ioctl"); exit(1); }

      fprintf(stderr, "bytes_deduped: %llu\n", range->info[0].bytes_deduped);
      fprintf(stderr, "status: %d\n", range->info[0].status);
      if (range->info[0].status == FILE_DEDUPE_RANGE_DIFFERS) {
         fprintf(stderr, "DIFFERS\n");
         break;
      } else if (range->info[0].status == FILE_DEDUPE_RANGE_SAME) {
         fprintf(stderr, "SAME\n");
      } else {
         fprintf(stderr, "ERROR\n");
         break;
      }

      if (range->info[0].bytes_deduped >= range->src_length) { break; }
      range->src_length -= range->info[0].bytes_deduped;
      range->src_offset += range->info[0].bytes_deduped;
      range->info[0].dest_offset += range->info[0].bytes_deduped;
   }
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: After experimenting on a 30Gb file, I can see that the implementation of `FIDEDUPERANGE` has horrible performance.  Not only does it have to verify that the files have identical contents, but it also has to reorganize the extent structure of the target file to match the source file.  Neither is it atomic over the entire range of the file, just (I presume) on an extent by extent basis.

Comment: `FICLONE` is *much* better performance-wise, but you, not the kernel, are responsible for making sure the data matches.  Also `FICLONE` has the unwanted side effect of changing the target file's timestamps, which can be fixed with `fstat` + `futimens`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older versions of `btrfs` (e.g., 4.15) had a 16 MiB limit per `FIDEDUPERANGE` call, and would silently cut oversized requests down to 16 MiB.  I forget exactly when the change happened, but the current version of `btrfs` (i.e., 5.16) loops in 16 MiB chunks.  I think linux (not `btrfs`, now) still silently cuts down requests over 1 GiB, though.  If you expect to use `FIDEDUPERANGE` with older versions of `btrfs`, you should definitely respect the 16 MiB limit.  Also, other filesystems might have a similar limit.

As for `src_length = 0`, you should really consult the documentation for the individual `ioctl`s for instructions on how to use them.  The `man` page for `FIDEDUPERANGE` you quoted correctly documents that `src_length = 0` means to dedup nothing.

Regarding the VFS page you quoted, things are just complicated.  `remap_file_range()` handles the functionality for multiple `ioctl`s adapted from `btrfs` that were originally designed and implemented separately in `btrfs`.  In the clone `ioctl`s, `src_length == 0` means clone to the end of the file.  In the dedup `ioctl`, `src_length == 0` means dedup nothing.  I forget exactly when, but there was an effort to unify the clone and dedup functions.  However, it's not very nice to change the `ioctl` interface of currently supported versions of `btrfs`.  In version 5.16, there's a weird hack involving `btrfs_remap_file_range_prep()` that converts the `len` argument to `remap_file_range()` depending on whether the `ioctl` was a clone or dedup call.  It's tempting to say the VFS documentation is wrong, since I don't think the `btrfs` behavior here has changed.  However, I'm not sure whether other filesystems have implemented `remap_file_range()` with this meaning of `len == 0`, so it's just complicated.